# Почему при добавлении (append) списка к самому себе создается бесконечно вложенный список?

Tags: python, список, append

Добрый день! Хотел бы понять почему функция append создает бесконечно вложенный список, если в аргумент вписать список который вызывает эту функцию.

```
l=[1,2,3]
l.append(l)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Ответ на этот вопрос в англоязычной версии SO...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28227428/5741205)

```
In [10]: l=[1,2,3]
    ...: l.append(l)
```

после `l.append(l)` ссылка (`reference`) на список `l` будет добавлена в конец списка, что приводит к рекурсии:

```
In [11]: l is l[3]
Out[11]: True

In [12]: id(l) == id(l[3])
Out[12]: True
```

как это сделать правильно:

```
In [14]: l.append(l[:])

In [15]: l
Out[15]: [1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3]]
```

если вам нужен плоский (не вложенный) список:

```
In [17]: l.extend(l)

In [18]: l
Out[18]: [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

`l[:]` - создает копию списка в памяти:

```
In [19]: l=[1,2,3]

In [20]: l[:] is l
Out[20]: False

In [21]: id(l[:])
Out[21]: 179393864

In [22]: id(l)
Out[22]: 197356744
```